# Is is possible add a stylesheet into the menu?

Tags: front-end, menu

I always use the `PastelColor` stylesheet in Mathematica 8, since I think it is comfortable to my eyes.  But it can be no longer found in the Menu in Mathematica 10, so I have to copy the stylesheet, for example,

*D:\Program Files\Wolfram \
Research\Mathematica\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets\Creative\P\
astelColor.nb*

to a specific directory, and choose it for every notebook I create.

I wonder  is there any way to include the style in the Menu in Mathematica 10, as is in Mathematica 8?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Evaluate `$InstallationDirectory`and from there open the directory $InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets. Make there a folder, say, entitled "Custom" and place your favorite StileSheets into this folder. Done. The folder will appear in the Menu/Format/StileSheet.

**Later edit**: One another way is as follows:

1. go to $InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets. That is, do not evaluate this whole line, but evaluate the `$InstallationDirectory`and then go to \SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets. There is a notebook `PastelColor.nb`in this folder. Hopefully, it is the one you need.
2. Open this notebook
3. Go to Menu/Format/OptionInspector. This opens a dialog entitled "Options for PastelColor.nb".
4. In this dialog identify the pop-down menu "Show option value" and select "PastelColor.nb".
5. In the Lookup text field type MenuSortingValue. Press Enter.
6. In the right window of the dialog the item "MenuSortingValue" will be highlighted. As soon as you have  no such entry it in the Menu/Format/StyleSheet, you should see the red cross to the left of this "MenuSortingValue" item and "None" to its right.
7. Click on the cross. It will disappear, and a number will appear to the right of this item instead of None. In my case it was 1100. It is the Menu position of this StyleSheet. In principle, you should have a possibility to change it. However, I tried, but did not succeed. Nevertheless, the postion 1100 is OK.
8. Press the "Apply" button at the top-right edge of the dialog and then close the dialog.
9. Save the notebook. Attention: you should not use the Menu/File/Save command or Ctrl+S, but only Menu/File/SaveAs. When you will be warned that such a file already exists, agree to replace it by the new one.
10. Close the file "PastelColor.nb". Done.

Be aware that the new StyleSheet will not appear in the menu, before you close Mma, When you open it once more, the StyleSheet should show up in the Menu.

**Second edit**: The menu position of the built-in StyleSheet is most probably blocked for changing.

One else thing that comes into head, you could create your own custom StyleSheet, which would carry all features of your favorite one, but it will be a custom one, and its menu position will be most probably not blocked.

This can be done as follows:

1. Open a new notebook and define a StyleSheet you typically use, when the PastelColor is not available.
2. Go to Menu/Format/EditStyleSheet. This opens the notebook "Private Style Definition for Untitled 1".
3. Go to $InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets and open the PastelColor.nb notebook.
4. Copy-paste the cells defining styles that you you like and use from the PastelColor.nb to the "Private Style Definition for Untitled 1" notebook.
5. You may also want to add here some other styles, that do not exist in the original PastelColor.nb, but are present in other StyleSheets. It is done analogously, by opening the corresponding StyleSheet notebook and copy/pasting the chosen style from there to your custom one.
6. Using SaveAs save the "Private Style Definition for Untitled 1" notebook  with a custom name, say, "PastelModified.nb" to the $InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets directory.
7. From the notebook PastelModified.nb go to the Menu/Format/OptionInspector. This opens a dialog entitled "Options for PastelModified.nb".
8. In this dialog identify the pop-down menu "Show option value" and select "PastelModified.nb".
9. In the Lookup text field type MenuSortingValue. Press Enter.
10. In the right window of the dialog the item "MenuSortingValue" will be highlighted.
11. Type there any position between 1 and 1999.

Done. It should appear in the menu. If this also does not work for you, there should be problems with your installation, and I recommend to redirect this question to the Wolfram Supporting Team.

Comment: I've tried as you said, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @yulinlinyu It works for me Win 7, Mma 10.0

Comment: Thank you. It is Win7,MMA 10.0 for me,too. Is there any possible reason?

Comment: @yulinlinyu  I cannot tell.

Comment: I can delete all the stylesheets in the menu by deleting all the folders in the directory, but I cannot add my own stylesheet.

Comment: @yulinlinyu Have a look at my later edit. I describe there an alternative way.

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch, neither method works for me.  With respect to the first method, PastelColor.nb already is in a folder, called Creative, in the location you specified, but it does not appear in the menu.  With respect to the second method, I proceed as far as clicking the cross, but it does not disappear.  MMA 10 beeps instead.  My operating system is Windows 8.1 64 bit.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and patient list. In my case, the value is 1500, and can be changed into 1100. But after pressing Apply button, it changes back into 1500, thus nothing happens for the modification.

Comment: @yulinlinyu Have a look at the second edit.

Comment: Thank you.But I'm sorry to say that it doesn't work either. The MenuSortingValueof the PastelModified is 1100 on my computer, and it refuses to change. I'll go for the suporting team.Thank you again for your patience and kindness.

Comment: @yulinlinyu Look, all this perfectly works for me, and not only for me. After all, I have the menu position of the PastelColor StyleSheet equal to 1100 and its nicely shows up in the menu. I guess, that you have a problem either with your program version or with the installation. I recommend to ask the Wolfram Support.

Comment: For me the cross next to MenuSortingValue is black instead of red. I cannot get rid of it! Anyone know why this might be the case?